# Manually back up large database

Tags: database

I'm trying to back up database (1.5 GB) but total download size is only 700 MB, why? Note that I'm trying to manually download/export database via phpMyAdmin. Of course I know how to get a database back up via SSH but I want to back up database via phpMyAdmin. Thanks.

Comment: what code did you use? How did you deteremine database size to be 1.5GB? and lastly, but most importantly, what is your question?

Comment: perhaps your backup does not contain e.g. generated indexes etc.

Comment: Thank you for answered to my question. Well - my question, I download database in phpMyAdmin (select database left menu) -> Go to Export -> Below "Go button" and download it. However, downloaded database sql file is not the real size. The real database sql file size 1.5 GB but downloaded file is 700 MB... I think there is a problem (allowed packed limits, etc.) I'm not sure. But already I'm getting backup via SSH, it's no problem.